# How to resize a matrix in a certain way in python?

Tags: python, math, matrix, scipy, interpolation

Before I implement a Neural Network, I need to preprocess some data. But I'm a noob in math and I can't find a function in Python to do what I want.

I have matrix like this:

```
[[0 4 ... 0 ]
 [0 3 ... 6 ]
 [0 3 ... 10]]
```

And I have a number, for example 7, which determines how many rows I must have in my new matrix after the transformation. What I want to achieve is this:

```
[[0 4    ...  0   ]
 [0 3.66 ...  2   ]
 [0 3.33 ...  4   ]
 [0 3    ...  6   ]
 [0 3    ...  7.33]
 [0 3    ...  8.66]
 [0 3    ...  10  ]]
```

You see that first column doesn't change because for each row in the original matrix the first is zero.
For the second column the first row decrease slowly on the four first row from 4 to 3 and after it stabilizes. 
And finally the last column increases from 0 to 10 passing by 6.

A math student told me that was an interpolation, but I can't find in scipy's documentation how to do that correctly.

Do you have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can click on the check mark next to the answer to accept it. It will show that the problem is solved. We don't change the title for that. (see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done! Thanks @ayhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.interp`. As it is only for 1D, I used a for loop.

```
import numpy as np

# You input matrix:
a = np.array([[0, 4, 0], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 10]])
# Put the shape you need here:
old_dim, new_dim = a.shape[1], 7
# Define new matrix
b = np.zeros((7, a.shape[1]))
# Define linspace that will serve for interpolation
nls, ols = np.linspace(0, 1, new_dim), np.linspace(0, 1, old_dim)
# Interpolate on each column
for col in range(old_dim):
    b[:,col] = np.interp(nls, ols, a[:,col])
print b
```

Output:

```
[[  0.           4.           0.        ]
 [  0.           3.66666667   2.        ]
 [  0.           3.33333333   4.        ]
 [  0.           3.           6.        ]
 [  0.           3.           7.33333333]
 [  0.           3.           8.66666667]
 [  0.           3.          10.        ]]
```

It is not a 2D interpolation function, but I am not very familiar with scipy (and numpy does not have any).

**Edit**
Fix issues with not square matrix

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 4, 0], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 10]])
old_dim, n_col, new_dim = a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 7
b = np.zeros((7, n_col))
nls, ols = np.linspace(0, 1, new_dim), np.linspace(0, 1, old_dim)
for col in range(n_col):
    b[:,col] = np.interp(nls, ols, a[:,col])
print b
```

My mistake, I inverted n_col and n_rows at some point.

Comment: I have this error :
`ValueError: fp and xp are not of the same length.` 


Because in my case ols and a[:, col] don't have the same length. 
Do you think it cans be adapt to work on non-square matrix?

Comment: But Thanks a lot @ Nuageux

Comment: @EPgg You are right indeed, see the edit for a correct version :)

Comment: You're the best! :D

Comment: Glad I was able to help you!